# Use parent document of the collection in firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is my firestore collection path `/chat/{doc}/messages`

I written rules like below,

```
match /chat/{documents=**}{
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
}
 
match /chat/{doc}/messages/{documents=**}{
  allow read, create:if request.auth.uid != null;
  allow update, delete: if false;
}
```

The problem is `messages` collection under the `doc`. I want to write rule like below for messages

```
match /chat/{doc}/messages/{documents=**}{
  allow read, create:if request.auth.uid in doc.data.users;
  allow update, delete: if false;
}
```

I am not well  experienced in firestore rules. Can someone help me to resolve the issues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understood it. But too late. Using firebase is just WASTE OF TIME!

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your question? What is the error you are facing? It is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can write firestore security rules that reference parent documents by querying for the parent document in the security rule with `get`:

```
match /chat/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}{
  allow read, create: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chat/$(chatId)).data.users
  allow update, delete: if false;
}
```

This answer is based on [Access other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in the Firebase documentation.